# Heroku not saving deploy settings

Tags: heroku

Everytime I try to set up automatic deployment for a `qa` branch, the UI doesn't give me any errors. However when I refresh the page, the deployment settings goes away and it asks me to enable for the `master` branch.

Before Refresh:

[image: Before Refresh]

After Refresh:

[image: After Refresh]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed once I pushed my code to the actual repo